# How to add a variable into a grep command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

I'm running the following grep command

```
var=`grep -n "keyword" /var/www/test/testfile.txt`
```

This work just as expected but I need to insert the file name dynamically from a loop like so:

```
var=`grep -n "keyword" /var/www/test/`basename ${hd[$i]}`.txt`
```

But obviously the use of ` brakes this with a unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``' and unexpected end of file

Any ideas of away around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't use `, and use a **function**:

```
mygrep() { grep -n "yourkeyword" "/var/www/test/${1##*/}.txt"; }
for (( i= 0; i < ${#hd[@]}; i++ )); do yourvar=$(mygrep "${hd[$i]}"); done
```

Comment: FGS? A little harsh. Sorry I was only asking im new to BASH/Shell give me a chance to learn that's why I ask

Comment: Fair enough: the use of backticks (`) to execute commands is discouraged and has been deprecated for many years now; $() is cleaner and offers less surprises, plus it is easier to quote and nest.

Comment: thank you, I have only learnt from reading other peoples code, I guess doing this may not be the best way as the code could be old, like in this case, lesson learnt.

Comment: I wholeheartedly recommend Greg Wooledge's wiki: http://wiki.wooledge.org for all things bash.

Comment: question on the above code what goes the @ do (or symbolise) in the ${#hd[@]}; line?

Comment: It evaluates to all members of the array, and is needed to calculate the number of elements with ${#}

Comment: Thank you learnt a lot from this one small piece of code :) I do seem to be getting a problem with this though. When I'm running it, its putting a /dev in the folder path like so: /var/www/test/dev/hd1.txt I guess its taking it from the following line /var/www/test/${1#*/}.txt but I can't see where its taking the /dev from

Comment: My bad, I should have given you the greedy match; post updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
var=$(grep -n "keyword" "/var/www/test/$(basename "${hd[$i]}").txt")
```

(observe the quotings, and, as adaptr mentioned, don't use backticks, but `$(...)` instead, as it's nestable).